# Postgres update нескольких таблиц

Tags: sql, postgresql

есть такая структура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хочу одновременно поменять `elem_id` в таблице `data` и в таблице `header_has_elem` на основании выборки в таблице `header` по полю `type`

Comment: `UPDATE` сразу двух таблиц невозможен. Вы можете сначала получить данные о том что на что обновлять во временные таблицы, а после того как все получите, обновляйте таблицы одну за другой

Comment: @Donil, смотря что понимать под "одновременно". Для СУБД я под этим понимаю "в одной транзакции", ибо гарантирует, что если что-то пошло не так, то изменений не будет. В этом случае вариантов масса, в том числе и использование темповых таблиц.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видится 2 варианта:

1. Хранимая процедура, например

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sync_update() 
   RETURNS void AS $$
   DECLARE
       h_id; -- результат из header
   BEGIN

   SELECT LIMIT 1 h.id
   FROM header AS h
   WHERE h.type = <значение> -- ваше условие
   INTO h_id;

   IF <условие, на основании кот. обновляем> THEN
       UPDATE data
       SET elem_id = <присваиваемое значение>
       WHERE header_id = h_id;
       UPDATE header_has_elem
       SET elem_id = <присваиваемое значение>
       WHERE header_id = h_id;
   END IF;
   ```

   END;
      $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
2. Команды выборки и обновления в транзакции

   BEGIN;
   -- Здесь все необходимые манипуляции по выборке и обновлению
   COMMIT;

Лично я бы предпочел в вашем случае использовать хранимую процедуру - так более гибко в плане программирования, к тому же не надо дополнительно заботиться о соблюдении целостности, т.к. внутри процедуры все манипуляции заключаются в транзакцию.

Comment: На любую разовую подобную задачу городить свою хранимку? Ну уж нет. Само собой, можно и хранимку темповой сделать, но зачем, если все решается значительно проще?

Answer (score 1):

В PostgreSQL давно уже имеются конструкции with, обернув в которые апдейт с возвращением новых значений можно обращаться к ним как к таблице. И никаких извратов с хранимками для столь мелочной задачи.

Приведенный код, возможно, придется адаптировать под эту задачу, ибо есть вероятность что я не корректно понял автора, однако, он показывает как использовать with для решения поставленной задачи и добиться желаемого внеся в него лишь небольшие изменения.

```
with new_data as (
  update data
  set elem_id = %new_value%
  where header_id = %header_id%
  returning *
)
update header_has_elem
set elem_id = (select d.elem_id from new_data d where d.header_id = header_id limit 1)
where id in (select a.id from analiz a join new_data d on d.header_id = a.header_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

С большой условностью "одновременного" обновления можно достичь, обвернув запросы в begin-commit ([BEGIN -- start a transaction block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-begin.html)). Это создаст транзакцию. того же эффекта можно достичь, обновляя таблицу 2 на событие в таблице 1, используя триггеры ([Overview of Trigger Behavior](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/trigger-definition.html))

Comment: Да не нужен никакой BEGIN/END. Транзакционность зависит от используемого инструмента. К примеру, если это pgAdmin - то любая запущенная разом пачка запросов - одна транзакция. Ну а ежели какие интрументы разработки, то сам себе хозяин, когда хочешь, тогда и закрываешь транзакцию.